# CloudConfigurationManager missing from Azure SDK v2.4?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk-.net

Can someone help me figure out where CloudConfigurationManager exists in Azure SDK v2.4?

CloudConfigurationManager, in the v2.3 SDK, is located in: 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure.NET SDK\v2.3\ref\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll

The 2.4 SDK is at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.4

And there's no such Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dll in that directory..

MSDN still shows CloudConfigurationManager in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Configuration.dl: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudconfigurationmanager.aspx

And so the only way I can get my project to compile is if I have both the 2.3 and 2.4 SDK installed at the moment.

Comment: Add Nuget package `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is in the folder **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.4\packages** as a local NuGet package (see below).  Also, there is a file in that directory titled LocalPackagesInstallationInstructions.docx that explains how to add it as a path for your NuGet Packages.  If you have a new dev environment installation (as I did recently) then you may find this helpful.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but why in the WORLD don't they publish this to nuget? :)

Comment: It's available there too.

Comment: Weird. I couldn't find a public package the last time I searched.. Guess I was searching for the wrong thing. I ended up finding the package on nuget today, and it showed as being installed already. However, I had to `update-package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager -Reinstall` to get it to show up as a reference in my project.

Comment: The answer works for me on win 7, vs 2013, azure SDK 2.9.
I cannot update nuget to the latest, so can not install online `Microsoft.WindowsAzure` and `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager`. The local installing Azure packages works for me, with the instruction doc at path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\packages".

Answer (score 14):

I found it in [`Microsoft.Azure`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt634650.aspx) as opposed to `Microsoft.WindowsAzure`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10879950)

Comment: Yes it does. I had exactly the same issue, to realise that the latter release had a change in namespaces, so if I had been asking the question, then it would have been the answer to my question.

Comment: This answer helped me too. If you're not aware the class is in a different namespace, the above answers doesn't help

Comment: Yes, seriously. the accepted answer is completely wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Latest Answer .
Install Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager.3.2.1 or newer

which contains Microsoft.Azure namespaces which is having this class. **CloudConfigurationManager**

Answer (score 3):

1.Download `Cloud Configuration NuGet` package

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager/

2.Install the package from local by solution `NuGet package Manager`

3.In code you will find class in `Microsoft.Azure.CloudConfigurationManager`

Comment: Searching for and installing "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager" from NuGet worked for me. Thanks for the nuget link to the package. That link also includes a command line installation method.