# CloudConfigurationManager incompatible with .NetCoreApp

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage

I have been trying to access Azure's Blob Storage in dotnet core with the following line of code:

```
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("<MyStorageName>_AzureStorageConnectionString")
            );
```

Beforehand I have installed the required Azure SDK, and updated it to the dotnet core compatible version, then, since `CloudConfigurationManager` was missing, I installed `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager`, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693143/cloudconfigurationmanager-missing-from-azure-sdk-v2-4) answer. After having updated this package as well, Package restore failed with the following error message:

```
Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.1 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
```

Is there any option in order to get `CloudConfigurationManager` working or do I need to find a workaround?

Comment: Are you using a cloud service ? Do you really need to use the CloudConfigurationManager or the ConfigurationManager is enough ?

Comment: @Thomas I am indeed using a cloud service, and I was following [this tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/vs-storage-aspnet5-getting-started-blobs/)

Comment: Ok I was wondering that the CloudConfigurationManager does not really make sens if you are using a web app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). Package Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 3.2.1 supports: net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)

In ASP.NET Core, the settings have been moved to appsettings.json. As far as I know, using `CloudConfigurationManager` with .NETCoreApp is not supported by now.

For a workaround, you could follow the code below to implement your `account`:

```
CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(
    new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(
        "<storage-accountname>",
        "<storage-accountkey>"), true);
```

Additionally, you could refer to this related [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30575689/how-do-we-use-cloudconfigurationmanager-with-asp-net-5-json-configs/30580006#30580006). Also, for a better understanding of Configuration in .NET Core, you could follow this [tutorial](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html).